# Cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects on dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

I am just trying to print the key and the value of a dictionary but I get the TypeError. 
The code:

```
def __str__(self):
    string = ""
    for key in self.dictionary:
        string += key, "-->", self.dictionary[key] + '\n'
    return string
```

I add for example the key 'key' and the value 'value', the content of the dictionary is correct:

```
{'key': 'value'}
```

But then I try to call the str method and get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "dictionary.py", line 37, in list
    print self.__str__()
  File "dictionary.py", line 42, in __str__
    string += key, "-->", self.dictionary[key] + '\n' 
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects
```

I don't know why this error shows up, the key is a string just like the value

Comment: `key, "-->", self.dictionary[key] + '\n'` is actually a tuple: `(key, "-->", self.dictionary[key] + '\n')`, which you can't add to a string with +=.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
string += key, "-->", self.dictionary[key] + '\n'
```

The commas between k, the arrow and the value make it into a tuple.

Try to change it into

```
string += key + "-->" + str(self.dictionary[key]) + '\n'
```

(you may need to wrap your key as `str(key)` as well, if you have keys that aren't strings.)

You can write this even cleaner as:

```
string += "%s-->%s\n" % (key, self.dictionary[key])
```

Comment: Ok, this was the problem: I had to close the interpreter and open it again in order to make it work, for some reason.

Comment: You also really should change the function to look more like this so you are not mutating the string over and over again. It's not a big issue on small data sets but if you do it with a very large data set it will slow down.
`return ''.join(['{}-->{}\n'.format(x, y) for x, y in self.dictionary.items()])`

Answer (score 5):

You are actually trying to concatenate tuple with a string on this line (note the commas):

```
string += key, "-->", self.dictionary[key] + '\n'
```

I think you meant to simply concatenate key with `-->` with value and a newline:

```
string += key + "-->" + self.dictionary[key] + '\n'
```

Comment: I changed it like you said and it's not working. I also tried to format it like "%s --> %s\n" % (str(key), str(self.dictionary[key])) but it doesn't work either

Comment: @xBlackout alright, what do you mean by "does not work"? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: It's solved, the problem was the interpreter, not the code. Thank you anyway

Comment: @xBlackout I _highly_ doubt that your Python interpreter was broken. Your interpreter was probably raising an error.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `format` method of the `String` object:

```
def __str__(self):
    string = ""
    for key in self.dictionary:
        string = "{}{}-->{}\n".format(string, key, self.dictionary[key])
    return string
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `,` in your string format line.

You have this

```
string += key, "-->", self.dictionary[key] + '\n'
```

When it should be this

```
string += key + "-->" + self.dictionary[key] + '\n'
```

---

This is what you currently have:

```
def __str__(self):
    string = ""
    for key in self.dictionary:
        string += key + "-->" + self.dictionary[key] + '\n'
    return string
```

A simple way to do the same thing:

```
def __str__(self):
    return ''.join(['{}-->{}\n'.format(x, y) for x, y in self.dictionary.items()])
```

Same as above but using C strings:

```
def __str__(self):
    return ''.join(["%s-->%s\n" % (x, y) for x, y in self.dictionary.items()]
```

One liner using a lambda:

```
def __str__(self):
    return ''.join(map(lambda x: '{}-->{}\n'.format(x[0], x[1]), self.dictionary.items()))
```

Same as above but using C strings:

```
def __str__(self):
    return ''.join(map(lambda x: "%s-->%s\n" % (x[0], x[1]), self.dictionary.items())
```